# LG WebOs How to get device Mac address?

Tags: javascript, webos, lg, smart-tv

Do somebody know, how to get the device Mac address of a lg smart TV with WebOs programmatically ?

I have a Smart TV application and want to read out the device Mac address of the lg smart TV.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get MAC address using WebOS internal apis.
If you happened to be looking for device unique id (UID) then this might help you.
 [Link to webos-service-api](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/device-unique-id/)

Answer (score 0):

Network scanner should do the job https://www.fing.io

Comment: Edited my question. Was meant to get the Mac address through my smart TV WebOs application.

Answer (score 0):

As you know webos is linux based system. It is possible to get mac address from file. It worked on webos.

Ethernet: file:///sys/class/net/eth0/address
Wireless: file:///sys/class/net/wlan0/address

```
<body onload="read_status()">
  <div class="macTest">

  </div>
</body>
```

A simple code for jquery;

```
function read_status() {
    $.get( "file:///sys/class/net/wlan0/address", function( data ) {
         $(".macTest").append("<h5>Mac Address: "+ data +"</h5><br>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must connection manager service for getting mac address, this a code example :

```
let mac = '';
let mac2 = '';
webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.connectionmanager", {
    method: "getinfo",
    parameters: {},
    onSuccess: function (args) {
        mac = args.wiredInfo.macAddress;
        mac2 = args.wifiInfo.macAddress;
    },
    onFailure: function (args) {
        
    }
});
```

Source : [https://www.webosose.org/docs/reference/ls2-api/com-webos-service-connectionmanager](https://www.webosose.org/docs/reference/ls2-api/com-webos-service-connectionmanager/)!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).